# tomato and dd-wrt alternatives

Tags: router, dd-wrt, tomato

Is there any other alternative for the most popular custom firmware for the router, dd-wrt and tomato.
I have a tp-link wr340g router. And its not supported on both.
I want the QOS(quality of service) feature to be added to my routers functions because I only have limited connection speed(.47Mbps). And I am sharing it with 1 person. I want to be able to have a bigger portion of that little .47Mbps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid your router's flash and memory sizes are too small : 2MB Flash, 8MB RAM.

This is why there is no alternative firmware for this router.

Comment: Pretty much any Linux-based firmware requires at least 4MB flash.

Answer (score 4):

it's just a g router.  you can get supported routers for 20 bucks on a bunch of different sites.  i know it technically doesn't answer your question but it's a much easier route.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [OpenWrt](http://openwrt.org/)?  When I Googled, I see there was mentioned of this model router.

Comment: The [Wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/wr340gd) for the similar WR340GD says: "Due the small amount of flash and RAM it cannot be offically supported by OpenWrt".